# Creating a graph class in R

Tags: r, class, methods, igraph

i'm new with R but i read lot of documentation about igraph and R

I'm trying to create a "Graph" class using igraph package in R

I created a graph from an invendeted adjacency matrix.

```
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjMatrix, mode="directed", weighted =TRUE)
```

It's correct how i created a graph class?

Now i have some problems how to implement some methods, for example add a new node or remove a node, return a value associated to a node, return a value associated to a edge, ecc.
I readed the documentation but i'm not sure how to implement those methods.

For example i writhe that for adding a new node:

```
g1 <- add_vertices(g1,1)
```

It's correct as method, if not, can someone give me help and an example?

I need help to understand.

Comment: You are misusing the concept of a class, see `?class`. Then there is nothing to implement or invent.. Keep reading the documentation and, in particular, the Examples section at the end of each function. Now your question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: Thanks forum the answer, but i already read the documentation typing ?Class, but i can't understand how to implement a Graph Class. Can you give me an example with a Graph?

Comment: As it says in `?graph_from_adjacency_matrix`, using this function returns an object of class `igraph`. Then most of the methods in the package accept objects of this class. There is nothing to implement and it's complete unclear what you mean by this "Graph" in the first place. I believe your question is how to use basic functions from the `igraph` package. Type `help(package = igraph)`, find a function that does what you need, and there you will always find examples at the end. However, I suspect that you need to have stronger basics in base R first (i.e., objects, types, functions, etc.).